# "would" vs "would have" in non conditionals

Tags: tense

On the net,I am finding sentences that use "would have" in the present.**Isn't this wrong?:**

> We estimate our software can save retailers up to 85 per cent of costs
>   they **would have** otherwise incurred from alterations.
>   -The Australian Financial Review

I am more comfortable with:

> This plan gives these employees a chance to cash out a benefit they
>   **would** otherwise be losing out on.-Medscape

I have read that in conditionals,"would have" is type 3 and used for past,but I dont know if these sentenses come under conditionals.

Comment: Don't get too hung up on those "numbered conditionals". They're just an imperfect attempt to codify how native Anglophones *actually* speak (which is nowhere near as clear-cut as implied by such numbering systems). Even though in your examples we know that in practice the retailers / employees ***are*** currently incurring costs / losing out, the context effectively "demotes" those outcomes to "hypothetical" by "promoting" the alternatives available with the new software / plan. In short, both your cited examples are syntactically and idiomatically fine.

Comment: Understood.Does this works if the case is reversed? Eg."If you have a good reputation, publishers will take a chance on projects they would turn down from an unknown"(instead of would have turned down).Is there any change in meaning?

Comment: With your *specific* example, both tense forms are fine, and I think only an obsessive pedant would claim there could be a difference. But in something like *John is dating a girl I would **marry / have married***, there's definitely a difference. In that one, *would marry* strongly implies a hypothetical alternative to the ***present*** circumstances (I might well be thinking that if the situation changes, I ***will*** marry her). But *would have married* strongly implies a ***past*** situation that didn't in fact come to pass (with only a weak implication that I would *still* marry her).